# Adding a gesture to a label?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer, unrecognized-selector

Swift 4 iOS 11

Trying to add a gesture to a label with this code, it fires but than crashes with an unrecognised selector.

Tried with and without @objc, tried too with @selector(ViewController.copyURL), tried turning on isUserInteractiveEnabled = true; none work

```
@IBOutlet weak var zeroURL: UILabel!

let press = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: zeroURL, action: #selector(copyURL))
view.addGestureRecognizer(press)

@objc func copyURL() {
    UIPasteboard.general.string = self.zeroURL.text
    print("copied")
    zeroURL.alpha = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75, delay: 0.25, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
        self.zeroURL.alpha = 1.0
    }) { (status) in
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your `zeroURL`?

Answer (score 3):

Target should be self, you need to add the gesture recognisor to the label, not the view

```
let press = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(copyURL))
zeroURL.addGestureRecognizer(press)
```

On the first line here you are configuring the gesture recognisor, telling it that the `self.copyURL` is the target action to use when that gesture is recognised. The second line adds the gesture to the `UILabel`

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
let press = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: zeroURL, action: #selector(copyURL))
view.addGestureRecognizer(press)
```

with

```
let press = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(copyURL))
zeroURL.addGestureRecognizer(press)
```

as the target should contain the implementation of the selector method

Answer (score 1):

Make the target `self` instead of `zeroURL` like below:

```
let press = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(copyURL))
zeroURL.addGestureRecognizer(press)

@objc func copyURL() {
    UIPasteboard.general.string = self.zeroURL.text
    print("copied")
    zeroURL.alpha = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75, delay: 0.25, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
    self.zeroURL.alpha = 1.0
    }) { (status) in
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Add long press gesture on your `UILabel` only not on your `view` like below:

```
zeroURL.addGestureRecognizer(press)
```

Comment: Yes, that fixes it... but I now have long press everywhere. I only want a long press on the zeroURL.